# How do I install the necessary debug packages to report tracebacks in Kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, bug-reporting, debugging

I've had many a Kubuntu install, but across all of them, I've had this problem. When KDE crashes, I get the "Crash Reporting Assistant" dialog that wants me to install debug symbols to get a full traceback. Invariably, and this has been the case for a long time (including and up to 12.10), I get this error:

*No debug packages could be found for the files listed below. Do you want to continue anyway?*

The following files are listed:

- /usr/lib/libkdeui.so.5
- /usr/lib/libsolid.so.4
- /usr/lib/libkdecore.so.5

Screenshot:

[image]

This has been an issue in Kubuntu for *years*. It happens on fresh installs, on old installs, on every Kubuntu install I've used since at least KDE 4 came out, if not before. There seems to be no way, without these debug packages, to make useful bug reports, because without them, the assistant won't let you finish the report, and thus, bugs go unnoticed.

I cannot believe I'm the only one noticing this. But I don't see any solutions out there from Google. I really want to help report bugs in KDE. Recommendations?

Comment: I don't know but what if you search for KDE debug packages with Muon?

Comment: Do you know how to search for a specific file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Documents**

KDE: http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Debugging/How_to_create_useful_crash_reports

It has a Kubuntu section: http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Debugging/How_to_create_useful_crash_reports#Kubuntu

Do you have the package: kdelibs5-dbg installed ?

Kubuntu bug wiki: https://wiki.kubuntu.org/Kubuntu/Bugs/Reporting

Comment: kdelibs5-dbg looks like the winner. I guess the wizard just didn't know to install it.