# Error reporting wizard does not work

Tags: kubuntu, bug-reporting, plasma, kde5

In Kubuntu 15.04 the K-Menu (application starter) keeps crashing multiple times each day. I would like to report the bug using the corresponding wizard but it does not work.

The wizard tells me that the report would be useless without installing debugging packages for additional information und refuses to send a report (even if I agree to input manual explanations). Anyway installing the debug packages does not work. It tells me it couldn't find the packages.

Installing kdelibs5-dbg (as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/249565/how-do-i-install-the-necessary-debug-packages-to-report-tracebacks-in-kubuntu)) didn't change the behaviour.

Any ideas how to fix the error reporting wizard? Which packages do I need to install so the wizard is satisfied?

**UPDATE**: There is a link in the wizard I didn't notice. It lists some files:

```
/usr/bin/plasmashell
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
```

How can I get the package names corresponding to those files?

**UPDATE2**: Just reproduced the issue again. This time an additional file

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/org/kde/plasma/private/kicker/libkickerplugin.so
```

appeared in the list. But the important part is: This time the wizard actually specified which debug packages where missing (it listed only the Qt5 libs). And it also was possible to install some debug package by itself ("plasma-desktop-dbg")! Very strange. The wizard didn't do anything useful dozend of times before. It looks to me like installing "apt-file" changed the situation. Could it be that the wizards needs that package?! Seems like I need an account on bugs.kde.org. I will create one and try to proceed and report here.

**UPDATE3**: I was able to report the bug and the wizard works fine now. I am not sure if installing "apt-file" actually fixed the issue but it looks like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Via `apt-file search`

```
/usr/bin/plasmashell
```

Therefore install `apt-file` via

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file
```

Now search packages of the files via

```
apt-file search --regex /usr/bin/plasmashell$
apt-file search --regex /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5$
apt-file search --regex /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5$
apt-file search --regex /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5$
```

The output is

```
plasma-workspace: /usr/bin/plasmashell

libqt5quick5: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5
libqt5quick5-gles: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5

libqt5widgets5: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
libqt5widgets5: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5.4
libqt5widgets5: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5.4.1

libqt5core5a: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
```

and therefore I would use

```
sudo apt-get install plasma-workspace-dbg
```

Comment: I also tried "sudo apt-get install plasma-workspace-dbg". Strange but apt-get insits that it is already installed. I have no idea why it was listed by the bug report wizard.

Comment: What about the Qt lib files? There are no "-dbg" version of those packages.

Comment: Yes, I know, this packages doesn't have debug packages.

Comment: Have you more information?

Comment: Like what? (sorry, I am a Linux beginner so it is hard for me to be creative by my own)

Comment: I have checked this list no QT5 debug packages http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/debug/

Comment: Hmm, a screenshot of the wizard.

Comment: Please see my third update.

Comment: I would say, you have solved your problem, great :)